# slick filter or where no longer support logical operations?

Tags: scala, slick, logical-operators, slick-2.0

I use slick 2.0.2 and I just want to do a simple filter or use a where sub-statement, I just want to do the logical operations like "and", "or" and "not" inside the filter :

```
val subjectdata = TableQuery[SubjectTable]
...
subjectdata.where(i=>(i.id===id && i.userId===rs.user.get.identityId.userId)).list()
```

and get error:

```
[error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\controllers\ShopController.scala:89: Cannot perform option-mapped operation
[error]       with type: (Long, String) => R
[error]   for base type: (Long, Long) => Boolean
[error]     subjectdata.where(i=>(i.id===id && i.userId===rs.user.get.identityId
.userId)).list()
[error]
                           ^
```

In slick 1.0.1 I can do:

```
val results = Query(TableClass)
.filter(r => r.isNull || r.expires > new Timestamp(DateTime.now().getMillis()))
.list
```

I want to do something similar on TableQuery in Slick2. How to do it?

Comment: Without knowing what `i.id`, `i.userId` and `rs.user.get.identifyId` are it's very difficult to guess what can be the problem.

Comment: Another thing, you are comparing two completely different things.

Comment: @pedrofurla it does not matter what rs.user.get.identifyId it is just regard it as constant. the issue is how to use and or not this logical operator here.

Comment: @user504909 - The compiler is reporting a type issue, which is what Scala is really good at. In particular, it looks like the type of `i.id` is not the same type as `id` or else the type of `i.userId` is not the same as `rs.user.get.identityId`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing to know is that Slick's operations are more strict about types than Scala's. Both operands have to have the same base type, optionally wrapped in an Options. So comparing a Double to Double or an Option[Double] is ok, but comparing it to an Int will give you such a compile time warning. The error message hints a bit you towards the problem

```
[error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\controllers\ShopController.scala:89: Cannot perform option-mapped operation
[error]       with type: (Long, String) => R
[error]   for base type: (Long, Long) => Boolean
[error]     subjectdata.where(i=>(i.id===id && i.userId===rs.user.get.identityId
.userId)).list()
```

In `(Long, String) => R` you see that the arguments do not have matching types and that the return type cannot be determined. So I assume either `id` or `rs.user.get.identityId` is a String. Turn is into an `Int` using `.toInt`. Alternatively you can convert the db-side value using `.asColumnOf[String]`.